# How to hide the macro in the macro browser, and only administrator can find it?

Tags: plugins, macros, confluence

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/macro-module/including-information-in-your-macro-for-the-macro-browser

If the "hidden" attribute for the plugin is "true" in the atlassian-plugin.xml, then the plugin can not be seen by both users and administrator.

Is there any way to hide the plugin but the administrator can find it in the macro browser to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible for "plugin-macros", you can only use this in "user-macros" [Create a User Macro: Visibility](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/writing-user-macros-4485.html#WritingUserMacros-visibility).

On Atlassian Answers there has been a workaround suggested ([How to enable a user plugin to show only for administrators?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/238651/how-to-enable-a-user-plugin-to-show-only-for-administrators))

1. Create a hidden plugin-macro
2. Create a user macro, which calls your plugin-macro
3. Make it only accessible for admins

This will not prevent normal users from including the macro directly to any page. But it will be visible in the macro browser for admins.